# adding a custom datalayer service in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

How do I add a custom datalayer on my angular4 app? the test I did only append the script to the end of  tag, I would like to add the script at the top, like the second line after

Here is the service I create, I also don't know if it's the best practice

```
            import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
            import { DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';

            @Injectable()
            export class DataLayerService {

                private headElement: HTMLElement;

                constructor(
                    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
                ) {
                    this.headElement = this.document.head;
                }

                public setDataLayerContent() {
                    var element: HTMLElement;
                    element =  this.document.write(`
                        <script>
                            dataLayer = [{
                              'pageCategory': 'test name',
                              'visitorType': 'any-value'
                            }];
                        </script>
                    `);
                    this.headElement.appendChild(element);
                }                    

            }
```

and the index.html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <base href="/">

            <!-- the script to be injected here -->

            <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com...........
```

Any ideas?

Comment: inside your setDataLayerContent method you could try -
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(yourscript);

Comment: sorry, I miss some edits on the method, for some reason your solution is not working, also it breaks when I add a block of script, html or multiline as document.write